# Does this triangle-area theorem have a name?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Given two distinct parallel lines and two distinct fixed points on one of the lines and a point that can vary on the other line. Then the areas of all the triangles formed by those 3 points are all equal. – Does this theorem have a name? I am not asking for an explanation of the mathematics, but simply an elevator-pitch name, something that rolls off the tongue more smoothly than "Do you know the area = one half base times height theorem?"

Comment: area = 1/2 base times height?

Comment: [I.37](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI37.html)

Comment: @Micah +1, hope you don't mind that I added your reference at the end of my answer.

Comment: @EulerSpoiler Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @gimusi: It appears that the answer to my question is 'no'. What would you suggest I do?

Comment: @EulerSpoiler it seems you have received two good answer, I wanted remind you that you can accept an aswer if it is a good answer to your OP. Otherwise of course you are not forced to accept any of them. Bye

Comment: @gimusi: I'm surmising that English is not your native language.

Comment: Yes indeed but I don’t think the point is that here. The answer to your question is no of course since the result comes directly from at least two other results. It can be considered as a simple corollary.

Comment: @gimusi: You may as well be speaking Esperanto.

Answer (score 16):

This is a particular case of [Euclid's Proposition 38 from Book I of the Elements](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI38.html):

> Triangles which are on equal bases and in the same parallels equal one another.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   Credit goes to @Micah's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884063/does-this-triangle-area-theorem-have-a-name/2884066#comment5955181_2884063) for pointing out that this particular case makes in fact the object of [Proposition I.37](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI37.html):

> Triangles which are on the same base and in the same parallels equal one another.

Answer (score 9):

It is a simply application of the formula for the area of the triangle that is

$$S=\frac12\cdot AB \cdot d$$

where $AB$ is the length of the segment between the two fixed point and $d$ is the distance between the two lines.

That property can be viewd also as a particular case of [**Cavalieri's Principle**](https://meangreenmath.com/2013/10/02/area-of-a-triangle-equal-cross-sections-part-2/)

[image]

Comment: How do you know that all three segments, at a given height in the above diagram, have the same length?

Comment: @EulerSpoiler it is explained in the given link, take a look here https://meangreenmath.com/2013/10/02/area-of-a-triangle-equal-cross-sections-part-2/

Comment: Okay, thanks. I took a tl;dr stance first time around, but now I see where you're coming from.